# How to a reach solid surface in 3d surface in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d, surface

How to reach a solid surface in 3d surface in matplotlib, please? I tried to apply plot_surface more times, but the refinement is limited and not enough. The transparency is still obvious. More sample also did not help.

```
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Coordinate for the cylinder
def data_for_cylinder_along_z(center_x,center_y,radius,height_z):
    z = np.linspace(0, height_z, 200)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
    theta_grid, z_grid=np.meshgrid(theta, z)
    x_grid = radius*np.cos(theta_grid) + center_x
    y_grid = radius*np.sin(theta_grid) + center_y
    return x_grid,y_grid,z_grid

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_zlim(0, 10)
 
ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), np.diag([0.4, 0.4, 1.6, 1])) # (x, y, z) ration of sides

theta1 = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r1 = np.linspace(-2, 0, 100)
t1, R1 = np.meshgrid(theta1, r1)

X1 = R1*np.cos(t1)
Y1 = R1*np.sin(t1)
Z1 = 3+R1*1.5+4

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')

ax.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z1, color="dimgray")
ax.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z1, color="dimgray")

# Cylinder
Xc,Yc,Zc = data_for_cylinder_along_z(0,0,2,4)

rep=10
for i in range(rep):
    ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, color = 'palegoldenrod')


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `antialiased` to `True` (found by trial and error, couldn't find description in the docs):

```
# Cylinder
Xc,Yc,Zc = data_for_cylinder_along_z(0,0,2,4)
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, color='palegoldenrod', antialiased=False)
```

[image]

Comment: @Elena-Greg: did this work for you and answer your question?